# ToString StringBuilder not displaying

Tags: java

For some reason my toString() is not working with the StringBuilder inputs but only with the System.out calls. If I do not have the System.out.println() calls it will print out blank lines. I have used StringBuilder before and have not had this happen before. I looked back at those programs and they are setup similar to the way I have it now. I am assuming it has something to do with the calls inside the StringBuilder?

I am still learning Java and would greatly appreciate your help. Listed here is my code for the program:

```
class NodeUMUC<T> {

private T element;
private NodeUMUC<T> next;
private NodeUMUC<T> prev;

// Default Constructor
public NodeUMUC() {
    next = null;
    prev = null;
    element = null;
}

//constructor
public NodeUMUC(T element, NodeUMUC<T> next, NodeUMUC<T> prev) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}

public void setElement(T element) {
    this.element = element;
}

public T getElement() {
    return element;
}

public void setNextNode(NodeUMUC<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public NodeUMUC<T> getNextNode() {
    return next;
}

public void setPrevNode(NodeUMUC<T> prev) {
    this.prev = prev;
}

public NodeUMUC<T> getPrevNode() {
    return prev;
}

} // End NodeUMUC<T> 

public class LinkedListUMUC<T> {

private NodeUMUC<T> head;
private NodeUMUC<T> tail;
private int size;

// Default Constructor
public LinkedListUMUC() {
    size = 0;
}

// Return size of the linked list
public int size() {
    return size;
}

// Check for items in linked list
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

// Add element at begining
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void insertHead(T element) {
    NodeUMUC<T> insert = new NodeUMUC<>(element, head, null);
    if (head != null) {
        head.setPrevNode(insert);
    }
    head = insert;
    if (tail == null) {
        tail = insert;
    }
    size++;
    System.out.println("Adding at head: " + element);
}

// Add element at end
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void insertTail(T element) {

    NodeUMUC<T> insert = new NodeUMUC<>(element, null, tail);
    if (tail != null) {
        tail.setNextNode(insert);
    }
    tail = insert;
    if (head == null) {
        head = insert;
    }
    size++;
    System.out.println("Adding at tail: " + element);
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T removeElementAt(int position) {

    return null;
}


// Remove element from end
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T removeTail() {
    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("Empty List");
    }
    NodeUMUC<T> reference = tail;
    tail = tail.getPrevNode();
    tail.setNextNode(null);
    size--;
    System.out.println("Removing from tail: " + reference.getElement());
    return reference.getElement();
}

public T peekElementAt(int n) {

    return null;
}

// Display the element at begining
public T peekHead() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    NodeUMUC<T> reference = head;

    try {
        System.out.println("Peeking head: " + reference.getElement());
    } catch (NullPointerException x) {
        System.out.println("Empty List");
    }
    return reference.getElement();
}

// Display the element at end
public T peekTail() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    NodeUMUC<T> reference = tail;
    try {
        System.out.println("Peeking tail: " + reference.getElement());
    } catch (NullPointerException x) {
        System.out.println("Empty List");
    }
    return reference.getElement();
}

// Display all items in the linked list
@Override
public String toString() {
    NodeUMUC<T> print = head;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //System.out.print("Items in List: ");
    while (print != null) {
        sb.append(print.getElement());
       // sb.append(print.getElement());
        System.out.print(print.getElement() + " ");
        print = print.getNextNode();
    }
    System.out.println();
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    //create object
    LinkedListUMUC<Integer> list = new LinkedListUMUC<>();

    //call methods for manipulation
    System.out.println("List Empty: " + list.isEmpty());
    list.insertHead(14);
    list.insertHead(25);
    list.insertHead(67);
    list.insertHead(98);
    list.peekTail();
    list.peekHead();
    list.toString();
    list.insertTail(2);
    list.toString();
    System.out.println("Size of List: " + list.size());
    list.removeTail();
    list.toString();
    System.out.println("Size of List: " + list.size());
    System.out.println("List Empty: " + list.isEmpty());

} // End Main
} // End LinkedListUMUC<T>
```

Comment: Which class is supposed these methods `removeElementAt` and `peekElementAt` belong to? I imagine there is some abstraction that contains `NodeUMUC` objects. Isnt't it?

Comment: They belong to the LinkedListUMUC class. I have the basic structure in the code and simply returning null.

Comment: Solved a portion of the issue. Still have the toString() StringBuilder issue.

Comment: You're not supposed to answer your own question inside your question. Questions (one question per question) should go into the question, and answers (you can self-answer your question) into an answer. Right now it looks like you are completely misunderstanding how StackOverflow works. Before you waste more of your own time, please read the **help center** *now*.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I apologize for not abiding by the rules. I have revised the question to only ask one question. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing with your logic; that's OK. It's just that `list.toString()` does nothing in the `main` method: You have forgotten to print out the returned value.

By the way, it would be clearer if `toString` inserted a comma between adjacent elements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. IDK if its because I am in Afghanistan and its late at night here or if I am just completely lost today but I can not resolve the issue. Do you mind giving me a quick hint?

Comment: @fox.josh Of corse. But if it is not related to this program, you'd better open another question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the assistance. I resolved the issue with:

```
    System.out.println(listOfInt.toString());
```